# muteLocalVideoStream not muting the video in agora

Tags: ios, react-native, agora.io

Iam new to react native. Iam using agora rtc (3.1.3) for video calling in my app. It works perfectly. We have some actions like switching camera and muting video etc. For muting video iam using the below code

```
 const toggleVideo = async () => {
    let mute = vidMute;
    console.log('Video toggle', mute);
    await (engine.muteLocalVideoStream(!mute));
    setVidMute(!mute)
}
```

Where engine is my RtcEngine created using my app id. Issue is muteLocalVideoStream has no effect on my video. Iam testing in iphone. Please help

Comment: Is this issue still present?

Comment: @vineethsrini yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `muteLocalVideoStream` method only stops the transmission of the video stream to remote users, it does not stop the video stream capture i.e. the local user can still view their video normally.

If you want to stop the video on the local user's device as well you can use the `enableLocalVideo` method instead. You can edit the code on line 4 - `await (engine.enableLocalVideo(!mute));`

I tried out your code on v3.1.6 of `react-native-agora` and everything works as expected.

Comment: Not working , the camera glitches for a sec and then continue recording , Error in log , Access denied findin
E/libc    (14043): Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
E/libc    (14043): Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
E/libc    (14043): Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
E/agora_vrp(14043): replaced by swap before render. gap=108 ms. all replaced by swap=2, stream=203280232
E/libc    (14043): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"

Comment: Thank you so much amazing answer:)

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func didClickMuteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
    agoraKit.muteLocalAudioStream(sender.isSelected)
    agoraKit.muteRemoteAudioStream(0, mute: false)
   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**